# R: Recognizing Geographical Coordinates within JSON

Tags: r, json

I am working with the R programming language.

**My Problem:** I am trying to recreate this map (e.g. in leaflet) here myself : https://crtc.gc.ca/cartovista/LTEOverTheYearsYE2019_EN/index.html (e.g. for 2019).

Here is what I have tried so far:

**Step 1 :** First, I downloaded the JSON for 2019:

```
library(jsonlite)
library(httr)


response <- GET("https://crtc.gc.ca/cartovista/LTEOverTheYearsYE2019_EN/map/LTE_YE2019.json")

content <- content(response, as = "text")

data <- fromJSON(content)
```

**Step 2:** Next, I tried to extract the longitude/latitude for all the polygons in this file and convert them into the correct Coordinate Reference System:

```
library(sp)
library(rgdal)

polygons <- lapply(LTE_YE2019$f$g$c[[1]], function(x) {
  Polygon(matrix(x, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE))
})

sp_polygons <- SpatialPolygons(list(Polygons(polygons, ID = 1)))


spdf <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(sp_polygons, data.frame(id = 1, row.names = 1))

proj4string(spdf) <- CRS(LTE_YE2019$proj)
```

The file now looks something like this:

```
> str(spdf)
Formal class 'SpatialPolygonsDataFrame' [package "sp"] with 5 slots
  ..@ data       :'data.frame': 1 obs. of  1 variable:
  .. ..$ id: num 1
  ..@ polygons   :List of 1
  .. ..$ :Formal class 'Polygons' [package "sp"] with 5 slots
  .. .. .. ..@ Polygons :List of 606

....

  .. .. .. .. .. [list output truncated]
  .. .. .. ..@ plotOrder: int [1:606] 321 322 324 329 330 325 372 290 267 373 ...
  .. .. .. ..@ labpt    : num [1:2] 994419 305033
  .. .. .. ..@ ID       : chr "1"
  .. .. .. ..@ area     : num 1.17e+11
  ..@ plotOrder  : int 1
  ..@ bbox       : num [1:2, 1:2] -2319216 -307601 2981680 3014094
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "x" "y"
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "min" "max"
  ..@ proj4string:Formal class 'CRS' [package "sp"] with 1 slot
  .. .. ..@ projargs: chr "+proj=lcc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-95 +lat_1=49 +lat_2=77 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs"
  .. .. ..$ comment: chr "PROJCRS[\"unknown\",\n    BASEGEOGCRS[\"unknown\",\n        DATUM[\"Unknown based on GRS80 ellipsoid\",\n      "| __truncated__
  ..$ comment: chr "FALSE"
```

**My Question:** When I try to plot this, I get the following error:

```
library(leaflet)

m <- leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addPolygons(data = spdf)

#Error in rgeos::createPolygonsComment(pgons) : 
  #rgeos_PolyCreateComment: orphaned hole, cannot find containing polygon for hole at index 2
```

**Step 3:** To solve this problem, I am trying to following approaches :

```
# Approach 1:

require(devtools)
install_github("eblondel/cleangeo")
require(cleangeo)

    report <- clgeo_CollectionReport(spdf)
    summary <- clgeo_SummaryReport(report)
    issues <- report[report$valid == FALSE,]
    
    spdf.clean <- clgeo_Clean(spdf)


# Approach 2 

library(rmapshaper)

spdf_clean <- ms_simplify(spdf)

m <- leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addPolygons(data = spdf_clean)

# Approach 3

library(sf)
library(leaflet)


sf_polygons <- st_as_sf(spdf)
valid <- st_is_valid(sf_polygons)
sf_polygons_valid <- st_make_valid(sf_polygons)


m <- leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addPolygons(data = sf_polygons_valid)
```

All 3 approaches seem to be taking a long time to run - in the meantime, I am not sure if I am approaching this problem correctly.

**Can someone please tell me if I am doing this correctly?**

How can I resolve this error to recreate this map in R/leaflet?

Thanks!

**Note:** Perhaps I have significantly overcomplicated this question. In the end, my main goal is to replicate these geographical maps as interactive leaflet maps in R - perhaps there might be an easier and more direct way to do this? I am open any suggestions!

Comment: hi! your transformed coordinates (`polgons`?) don't appear to actually be coordinates. The file itself is incomprehensible. Am I missing something? Every GeoJSON reader I put this into throws a fit. It seems like they intentionally made it impossible to use

Comment: @Mark: hello! Thank you for your reply! Maybe I have overcomplicated everything? A KMZ version of this map can be found here : https://crtc.gc.ca/eng/publications/reports/policymonitoring/2020/cmr4.htm ... maybe this will be easier to work with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full credit for JSON parsing goes to [Spacedman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/211116/spacedman), his answer - https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/461914/213352 - to the related question basically solved the current one. The following is just a purrr-heavy attempt to pack it all together with some questionable map hole handling thrown in -- some of those polygons are holes and some are islands in holes, probably with matching ring directions. Here holes were handled through rather crude combination of predicates, unions and removals.

```r
library(jsonlite)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(sf)
library(sfheaders)
library(leaflet)

vect_to_sfg <- function(coord_vect){
  # input vector of differential coordinates, 
  # [1] & [2] are refernces for x & y:
  # int [1:18242] 2016758 388079 -1045 -494 -1046 -494 ...
  
  # convert to 2 column matrix
  #          [,1]   [,2]
  # [1,] 2016758 388079
  # [2,]   -1045   -494
  # [3,]   -1046   -494  
  
  # apply cumsum to columns to transform differential values to 
  # absolute (x,y) coordinates
  #         [,1]   [,2]
  # [1,] 2016758 388079
  # [2,] 2015713 387585
  # [3,] 2014667 387091
  
  # convert to sfg, a single polygon geomtery
  matrix(coord_vect, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE) %>%  
    apply(2, cumsum) %>% 
    sfheaders::sfg_polygon()
}

# list of vectors ( -> list of polygons ) -> sf geometry column
vect_list_to_sfc <- function (coord_vect_list) {
  map(coord_vect_list, vect_to_sfg) %>% 
    st_sfc()
}

# crude approach to cut out holes
make_holes <- function(sfc){
  p_union      <- st_union(sfc)
  hole_mask    <- st_contains_properly(p_union, sfc, sparse = FALSE)
  hole_union   <- st_union(sfc[hole_mask])
  island_mask  <- st_contains_properly(hole_union, sfc, sparse = FALSE)
  island_union <- st_union(sfc[island_mask])
  st_difference(p_union, hole_union) %>% st_union(island_union)
}

#### fetch and process

base_url <- "https://crtc.gc.ca/cartovista/LTEOverTheYearsYE2019_EN/map/"
jsons <- paste0("LTE_YE", 2014:2019, ".json")

# request and parse jsons, returns list of (proj string; geometry)
j_resp <- set_names(jsons) %>% 
  map(\(json_f) fromJSON(paste0(base_url, json_f))) %>% 
  map(\(j) list(proj = pluck(j, "proj"),
                geom = pluck(j, "f", "g", "c", 1)))

# sample from j_resp:
glimpse(j_resp)
#> List of 6
#>  $ LTE_YE2014.json:List of 2
#>   ..$ proj: chr "+proj=lcc +lat_1=49 +lat_2=77 +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-95 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,-0,-0,-0,0 +units=m +no_defs "
#>   ..$ geom:List of 265
#>   .. ..$ : int [1:18242] 2016758 388079 -1045 -494 -1046 -494 -1045 -493 -1045 -493 ...
#>   .. ..$ : int [1:2182] 1472249 -197163 -1189 -360 -1188 -360 -1189 -360 -1188 -360 ...
#>   .. .. [list output truncated]

# extract proj strimgs
projs <- map(j_resp, "proj")

# extract geometry vector lists, 
# convert to sf geometry columns, 
# handle holes (overlapping geometries),
# set proj for every sf object,
# transform to WGS84 for leaflet

# result is a list of sf objects, one multipolygon per each input json

lte_sf_lst <- j_resp %>% 
  map("geom") %>% 
  map(vect_list_to_sfc) %>% 
  map(make_holes) %>% 
  map2(projs, \(geom, proj) st_sf(geometry = geom, crs = proj)) %>% 
  map(st_transform, crs = "WGS84")

# helper for reduce2, add new polygon layer to existing leaflet object
addPolygons_reduce <-  function(map, polygon, name){
  addPolygons(map, data = polygon, group = name, weight = 0, 
              fillColor = "#3b528b", fillOpacity = .2)
}

# inital Leaflet object, no layers, serves as .init argument for reduce2
lte_leaflet <- leaflet() %>% 
  addProviderTiles(providers$CartoDB.Positron)

# use reduce2 to add all collected layers to Leaflet,
# iterate through lte_sf_lst list and call addPolygons_reduce() on 
# each object, initial map being lte_leaflet
lte_leaflet <- reduce2(lte_sf_lst, 
                       names(lte_sf_lst), 
                       addPolygons_reduce, 
                       .init = lte_leaflet) %>% 
  # add layer contorls
  addLayersControl(overlayGroups = names(lte_sf_lst), 
                   options = layersControlOptions(collapsed = FALSE))
lte_leaflet
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-06-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>